# How do I customize the line label spanner line in a gt table

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to customize a `gt` table to my liking, but somehow I cannot add a custom line between the header and the row of spanners.

```
library(gt)
library(magrittr)

gt(head(mtcars, 10)) %>% 
  opt_table_lines("none") %>% 
  tab_spanner(label = "subset1", columns = 1:3, id = "one") %>% 
  tab_spanner(label = "subset2", columns = 7:9, id = "two") %>%
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = "right"),
            locations = list(cells_column_spanners(spanners = "one"),
                             cells_column_labels(3),
                             cells_body(3)
            )) %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = "top"),
            locations = cells_body(rows = c(1))) %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = "bottom"),
            locations = cells_column_labels()) # this does not do anything when label spanners are defines as like now, but it does when spanners labels are not defined
```

**Current output**
[image]

**Desired output**
[image]

**Troubles**

I want the output as pictured above, but in my own attempt to 'clean' the table of any abundant lines, I used `opt_table_lines("none")`, but I am not sure if this is the correct use of it.

It seems like the spanner labels somehow interfere with the top line in the header. I tested this by not defining the spanner labels, and then the code does produce a top border line above the column names.